# How can I put speed limits on ports?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw, port-forwarding

I have UFW enabled, so the solution should not interfere with it. It should also work after reboot.

I currently know these commands which limit the data usage of ports:

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -m quota --quota 50000000000 -j ACCEPT
```

But I don't know how to persist these without affecting UFW, and I very much prefer a speed rate limit.

Update: It seems I've got to use `tc`. If it should work (I'm optimistic), I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool *wondershaper* to perform that.

This is my network speed before the configuration of *wondershaper* (I used the tool speedtest-cli to test my network in a terminal) :

[image: Speed test before limitation]

And then I limit my speed and perform a new speed test :

[image: Speed test after limitation]

This is the command : `wondershaper [interface] [downspeed] [upspeed]` (kb/s).

To clear the limit use the command `sudo wondershaper clear <INT>`.

Hope this is what your looking for. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for ports?

Comment: You can use `trickle -u {up} -d {down} {program}`. Please check this [article](http://jwalanta.blogspot.fr/2009/04/easy-bandwidth-shaping-in-linux.html) of Jwalanta Shrestha .

Comment: This trickle thing is also interesting, but unfortunately, my need is exactly limiting ports, not programs. I have a single program running on several ports, and each port needs to be limited separately.

Comment: I don't know any other tools, `tc` looks great. I'm also interesting by the result.